# Custom exel function with macro vba and sql server database

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a Sql Database with Table=Data_table

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th> 
    <th>AGE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123AB</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456CD</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>789EF</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make an excel macro that will give me the following function in Excel:
Allowing me to display name on B1 using SQL queries whith my Custom function (=SQLSelect(A1)).

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>A</th> 
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>123AB</td>
    <td>=SQLSelect(A1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have done so far:

```vb
Function SqlSelect(n As String) As String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=pass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Data Source=IT\SQLEXPRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Database"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT NAME FROM data_table where ID='" + n + "'"

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    n = rst.GetString
End Function
```

I hope this question is not too confusing and I appreciate your help!

Comment: OK I'm confused.  Is the HTML in your question supposed to be markdown or are you actually *retrieving* HTML from the database?

Comment: That's not how you return a value from a function: should be `SqlSelect = rst.Fields("Name").Value`.  You should probably check for rst.EOF before tryin to read the field value though.

Answer (score 4):

```vb
Function SqlSelect(n As String) As String

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String

    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=pass;Persist Security Info=True;" & _
              "User ID=sa;Data Source=IT\SQLEXPRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
               "Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;" & _ 
                "Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Database"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT NAME FROM data_table where ID='" + n + "'"

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    If not rst.EOF Then
        SqlSelect = rst.GetString
    Else
        SqlSelect = "???"
    End If
End Function
```